# overloading post/pre increment operators

Tags: c++

I'm having an issue overloading the post/pre ++ operator. So I have my main class `Nodelist` and from this class I have a function that prints. The print function uses the `Iterator` class to access the `++` operator function. Everything works fine until it reaches the `temp++;` which causes an infinite loop; I'm using this for a linked list and while I know that `nodePntr->next` allows me to move to the next node I'm not sure why this does not work?

**Node**

```
struct node {
    int info;
    node* next;
};
```

**Nodelist**

```
class NodeList {
public:
    void Print();
private:
    node* header;
};

void Nodelist::Print()
{
    Iterator temp;

    temp = header;
    while (!temp.isNull()) {
        cout << *temp << " ";
        temp++;
    }
}
```

**Iterator**

```
class Iterator {
public:
    friend class Nodelist;
    Iterator();
    Iterator(node *);
    bool isNull();
    node operator++();
    node operator++(int);
private:
    node* nodePntr;
};

node Iterator::operator++()
{
    node *temp = nodePntr->next;
    return *temp;
}

node Iterator::operator++(int)
{
    node *temp = nodePntr;
    ++temp;
    return *temp;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your increment functions need to return values of type `Iterator`, not `node`, and should update the internal node stored by the iterator. Your loop never actually modifies the `temp` object in your `Print` function, hence the infinite loop.

For example, your pre-increment function might look something like this

```
Iterator& Iterator::operator ++ ()
{
    // Update the node inside the iterator.
    nodePntr = nodePntr->next;
    // Return a reference to the updated iterator.
    return *this;
}
```

and then your post-increment can be written in terms of your pre-increment

```
Iterator Iterator::operator ++ (int)
{
    // Make a copy. A working copy constructor is left as an exercise to the reader.
    Iterator temp(*this);
    // Call the pre-increment (code reuse);
    ++(*this); 
    return temp;
}
```